# python remove all whitespace from entries in a list

Tags: python, string, list

while calling `readlines()` on  a .srt file , I got a list of characters with lots of leading and trailing whitespace like below

```
with open(infile) as f:
    r=f.readlines()
    return r
```

I got this list

```
['\xef\xbb\xbf1\r\n', '00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:03,000\r\n', "[D. Evans] Now that you've written your first Python program,\r\n",'\r\n', '2\r\n', '00:00:03,000 --> 00:00:06,000\r\n', 'you might be wondering why we need to invent new languages like Python\r\n', '\r\n']
```

I have only included a few elements for brevity..How do I clean this list sothat I can remove all whitespace characters and get only the relevant elements like

```
 ['1','00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:03,000',"[D. Evans] Now that you've written your first Python program"...]
```

Comment: The `\xef\xbb\xbf` looks like a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: when I open the .srt file in vi ,I can see ^M characters after each line..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can strip each line. Running it as a generator could also save you some memory if you're working on a big file.

Also, looks like you're working on a UTF-8 file with a BOM (which is sort of silly, or at least unnecessary) for the first several characters, so you need to open it differently.

```
import codecs

def strip_it_good(file):
    with codecs.open(file, "r", "utf-8-sig") as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.strip()
```

Comment: `strip()` doesn't seem to get rid of the `'\xef\xbb\xbf1\r\n'` sequence properly leaving only '1' when I try this. It just strips of the trailing `\n`

Comment: I know it will get rid of the \r\n. Technically \xef\xbb is the BOM so it's not whitespace. I usually manually dump the first 2 characters of the file in a preparser if I detect it's a BOM.

Comment: ah ok, but from output the OP shows it should just be `'1'`, no? (my first thought was also `strip()`, I got dissuaded from using it by a comment :)

Comment: Yeah let me see if I can find the correct pythonic way of ignoring the BOM.

Comment: that does the job I think .. Now I get `[u'1', u'00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:03,000', u"[D. Evans] Now that you've written your first Python program,", u'', u'2',...]` ..thanks ..codecs.open was new for me

Comment: @damon glad it worked for you. The minor difference here is that you're using unicode strings rather than regular strings now, but since you're likely just using English you probably won't notice at all.

Comment: Oh, and I wasn't trying to insult you about the BOM. I figured you were a consumer of the file. It's just pointless for UTF-8 files.

Comment: Why are you using `readlines()`? `for line in f:` will do the job just as well, without the upfront penalty of reading the entire input file.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I copy/pasted from the original and forgot to change it. Thanks for the extra eyeballs.

Comment: @Jordan maybe you should put this generator into a function to make it complete and working.